# Is export server ready to Highcharts V3?

Tags: highcharts, export, beta

Does anybody knows if Highcharts exporting server at export.highcharts.com is currently supporting Highcharts 3.0beta? I'm trying to send my bubble charts to it and it fails, and displays a common error...

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Yes it is, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/g8JcL/64/ Make sure you have also latest exrpoting module. If this is not working, could you recreate issue on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

A small test on jsFiddle with my own Highcharts config, and I find : Highcharts export server seems to be strict on which characters are sent to it. And I was sending it some... strange... characters ; replacing them fixed the problem.

Hope it will be useful to others,
Thanks !